Microsoft Graph API - Generate PowerPoint slides thumbnails
Creating "thumbnails" is possible to do from graph api for a powerpoint, but the only catch is, that it creates only for the first slide and the others are not there.
I want to generate large thumbnails for each slide there is
Is it possible that anyone has ever reached a solution for this?
